# Unable to start DSE 5.0.9

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

This is the error we get - very undescriptive.

Running DSE on Centos 6.7

```
ERROR [main] 2017-08-08 22:55:43,839  CassandraDaemon.java:664 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AssertionError: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.ColumnDefinition.<init>(ColumnDefinition.java:157) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.createColumnFromRow(SchemaKeyspace.java:1060) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.lambda$fetchColumns$12(SchemaKeyspace.java:1038) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchColumns(SchemaKeyspace.java:1038) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTable(SchemaKeyspace.java:988) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTables(SchemaKeyspace.java:952) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:911) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspacesWithout(SchemaKeyspace.java:888) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchNonSystemKeyspaces(SchemaKeyspace.java:876) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:137) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:127) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:241) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:463) ~[dse-core-5.0.9.jar:5.0.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:568) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.13.1735.jar:3.0.13.1735]
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91) [dse-core-5.0.9.jar:5.0.9]
```

Can anyone chime in?

Comment: Hi, is this the only error you see? Perhaps you could share the full `system.log` and the `output.log` via a github gist or similar?

Comment: This is the only error. The server is starting up as usual (loading tables, etc) and then this error happens and it dies.

Perhaps I should mention that this specific node was upgraded to 5.1.2 and then downgraded back. Just a "small" detail ... :)

Comment: I can see the version above in DSE5.0.9. If you upgraded to 5.1.2 you would have had to run sstable upgrade, did you? If so then this might be why you see this.